# E-Mail spam from localhost without having an open relay

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, postfix, email-server

I use ubuntu with postfix/dovecot for e-mail purpose.
Now I have the problem that mails are being sent by unauthorized user, despite the fact that I don't have an open relay.

My `mail.log` contains such lines:

```
Mar  9 14:12:00 my-host postfix/pickup[10204]: 670148A00C6: uid=10002 from=<spam@sender.com>
Mar  9 14:12:00 my-host postfix/cleanup[12610]: 670148A00C6: message-id=<c94dd1e890114811b2f62c221380c5da@my-host.com>
Mar  9 14:12:00 my-host postfix/qmgr[9110]: 670148A00C6: from=<spam@sender.com>, size=780, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar  9 14:12:01 my-host postfix/smtp[12594]: 670148A00C6: to=<victim@mail.ch>, relay=mx1.data.ch[212.212.212.212]:25, delay=1.1, delays=0.1/0/0.55/0.49, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 6F6A0200C0)
Mar  9 14:12:01 my-host postfix/qmgr[9110]: 670148A00C6: removed
```

I thought my postfix setup is correct :

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/blacklists, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org
```

Where does the mail come from? I don't see a login from the spammer, so it has to be some script on the host. I really would like to locate the source but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The  [pickup(8)](http://www.postfix.org/pickup.8.html)  daemon  waits  for hints that new mail has been
>   dropped into the **maildrop** directory, and feeds it into the  [cleanup(8)](http://www.postfix.org/cleanup.8.html)
>   daemon. Ill-formatted files are deleted without notifying the
>   originator.
>
> ---
>
> [**The "maildrop" queue**](http://www.postfix.org/QSHAPE_README.html#maildrop_queue)
>
> Messages that have been submitted via the Postfix [sendmail(1)](http://www.postfix.org/sendmail.1.html) command,
>   but not yet brought into the main Postfix queue by the [pickup(8)](http://www.postfix.org/pickup.8.html)
>   service, await processing in the "maildrop" queue.

Therefore, the first line tells that the mail comes from a local source via Sendmail:

```
Mar  9 14:12:00 my-host postfix/pickup[10204]: 670148A00C6: uid=10002 from=<spam@sender.com>
```

It also tells that the **originating user has UID 10002**. Look for any scripts run as that user. I'd first compare the web server logs for the user i.e. the VirtualHosts related to that account – at and just before `Mar 9 14:12:00`. That might reveal a HTTP request (most likely a `POST` request) that was used for sending this email.

Comment: Thanks the source was a buggy/old public contact form in joomla which was misused by spambots.
I could identify it with the access-logs.